# Gravity forms populate address and time field

Tags: wordpress, forms, gravity-forms-plugin, gravity, gravityforms

I am trying to populate address and time field in gravity forms. The following code does only work for normal fields but sadly not for address and time fields.
What am I doing wrong? Any advices? Sadly there is no documentation about how to populate date or adress fields.
Field 3 is a time field. Field 27 adress fields.

```
foreach($form["fields"] as &$field)
    switch($field["id"])
    {
        case "26": $field["defaultValue"] = $global_turnier_id; break;  
        case "1": $field["defaultValue"] = $turnier_name; break;
        case "27.1": $field["defaultValue"] = $street; break;   //--> not working
        case "3.1": $field["defaultValue"] = "12:00:00"; break;     //--> not working
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're better off using the `gform_field_value` filter as described here:

https://docs.gravityforms.com/using-dynamic-population/#hooks

Might look something like this where "my_time" is the dynamic population parameter set on your time field.

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_value_my_time', 'dyn_pop_my_time' );
function dyn_pop_my_time( $value ) {
    return '12:00';
}
```